# Directive template update when scope property updates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I have a component I'm trying to build that accepts a `user_id` and then loads user information for it in the background, and then drops an element on the page with another directive attached to it.

So far this is what I have

```
<user-popover user-id="item.item_high_bid_user_id"></user-popover>

angular.module('bidrAdminApp')
  .directive('userPopover', ['Data', function (Data) {
    return {
      template: '<a bb-popover-template="user-popover-content.html">{{user.user_name}}</a><i ng-hide="{{user}}" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
      scope: {
        userId: '=',
        user: '=*'
      },
      restrict: 'E',
      controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, Data){
        Data.getUser($scope.userId).then(function(userData){
          $scope.user = userData.data;
        });
      },
    };
  }]);
```

I'm getting data loading in the background from my `Data` service and the `user.user_name` in the template gets updated correctly, the issue is the spinner is not being hidden when the `$scope.user` gets updated. How can I get the spinner to hide once the user data has been loaded in and the rest of the template has been updated.

**UPDATE**

I need to mention here that these directives show up in a repeating grid of items, this directive is intended to act sort of like a user hover card, similar to facebook when you hover over someone and you get a popover with some information about the user, so I would really like each iteration of this directive be able to stand on its own, as it stands now the loading indicator hides after all the directives have finished loading their `$scope.user` property.

Comment: just drop the 'user: '=*'' part in your directive scope, should be fine i guess.

Comment: @Gatsbill the spinner still stays if I remove this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
ng-hide="user.user_name.length > 0"
```

Comment: No the spinner is still there.

Comment: `ng-hide` takes an expression directly, no need to wrap it with brackets.

Comment: Right I edited the answer, also the property is user_name not name

Comment: Ah I see what's happening, the spinner removes when the last directive on the page finishes loading, is this a scope problem?

Comment: btw why did you bind scope property with "=*" ? just curious

Comment: So you have more directives on the page like this?

Comment: yes I have a repeating grid of items, these items have bidders, represented as this user-popover directive (think facebook when you hover over a user you get a popover with their info)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the scope from your directive and use `$attrs.userId`

```
angular.module('bidrAdminApp')
  .directive('userPopover', ['Data', function (Data) {
    return {
      template: '<a bb-popover-template="user-popover-content.html">{{user.user_name}}</a><i ng-hide="{{user}}" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
      restrict: 'E',
      controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, Data){
        Data.getUser($attrs.userId).then(function(userData){
          $scope.user = userData.data;
        });
      },
    };
  }]);
```